# How to get the key downs in Qt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I would like to have a list to control what keys are currently down in an application made in qt. I used the `keyPressEvent` and `keyReleaseEvent` for controlling when a key gets pressed and put in the list and removing it when it gets released using the `event.key()`.
The problem is that when a key is down it doesn't leave the key as pressed, it alternates the event between released and pressed. Now, the `isAutoRepeat` function controls if the key is repeated, so if this is false then I add or remove the key. This works just fine in Windows but in Linux the `isAutoRepeat` function always return false and the key alternates between pressed and released when it is in fact pressed. What i like to do is to have in the list the keys that the user is pressing right now, for example for a WASD control, so my question is if there is a way to control this using pure Qt? because i have emulated this behaviour measuring the time when the previous key was pressed or released.
My functions are as follows:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if not event.isAutoRepeat():
        self.keys.append(event.key())

def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if not event.isAutoRepeat():
        self.keys.remove(event.key())
```

Comment: Hi @r010. Welcome to SO. Make sure you be very clear with your question statement. Suggestion: Add a "QUESTION: <your question statement>" just before or after your problem description.

Comment: According to the [docs for isAutoRepeat](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#isAutoRepeat), its behaviour can be indeterminate on *any* platform (not just Linux). It would help if you could clarify what *specific* problem are you trying to solve with this functionality. What is the purpose of the list of events? Why are you trying to control key presses?

Comment: Actually it should work correctly for single key events. If it's not, it looks like a bug in Qt.